# Git plumbing - find out if there are any unstaged files in a directory quickly

Tags: git, bash

In a bash script I want to know if there are unstaged files in a directory.

The closest I can get is checking the exit code of this:

```
git ls-files --other --error-unmatch --exclude-standard --directory "$folder/" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

There are 2 downsides.

1. I have to use a different command to check if a file is unstaged (Because of the slash)
2. This will print all the files to `/dev/null` before exiting, which can take a long time on certain repos

Ideally, I'd like a way for it to stop as soon as it finds an untracked file - I don't need to know what they are, just if they're there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy with the git command, you can pipe to `grep -q`, whose return code will tell you if there is any output:

```
git ls-files --other --exclude-standard --directory "$folder/" | grep -q .
```

As soon as grep receives any input, the pattern `.` is matched and it exits sucessfully.

To suppress error output, you can wrap the whole thing in curly braces `{ }` and add `2>/dev/null` to the end.

Another option would be to parse the output of `git status`. For example, to see if any files in the output have a path starting with `$directory`, you could use this:

```
git status --porcelain | awk -v dir="$dir" 'index($2, dir) == 1 { found = 1; exit } END { exit !found }'
```

If your version of awk supports setting the record separator to a null byte, you could use `git status -z` instead:

```
git status -z | awk -v RS='\0' -v dir="$dir" 'index($2, dir) == 1 { found = 1; exit } END { exit !found }'
```

To filter out untracked files, you could add a check for `$1 != "??":

```
git status -z | awk -v RS='\0' -v dir="$dir" '$1 != "??" && index($2, dir) == 1 { found = 1; exit } END { exit !found }'
```

Comment: Yes, the same is true for `sed 1 q` but even if the piped program exits the script won't continue until the original command ends. You can test this like so: `( echo -e "test\ntest" && sleep 5s ) | grep -q .`

Comment: I'm not sure that your test is the same - maybe a better example would be `find . | grep -q .` in a directory containing a large number of files. The program exits almost immediately, whereas it takes a lot longer without the pipe to grep.

Comment: You're right - I should assume this is something to do with buffering. That said: if it takes a long time to find the files in question it's still going to hang until it's gone through the entire directory structure, so this still isn't ideal. Ideal would be a dedicated plumbing command or something

Comment: @JV I've added a couple of other suggestions that might be useful.

Comment: `git status --porcelain` was the original code that ran even slower than `ls-files` - I guess there isn't any better way to do this as of yet - I'll just mark you as answer since you did point out the buffering thing

Comment: Don't feel obliged to accept my answer if you're not happy with it! Perhaps someone else will come up with something better.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is faster or slower, but `git clean -n` would list unstaged files.

This doesn't solve the problem of "stop as soon as first unstaged file" is found, but it seems that there is no good way to do that.